# python lowest cost of checking various equalities at once

Tags: python, list

I start with a list full of `False` elements.
Then those elements are switched to `True` independently over the course of iterations.
I need to know when the list is fully True.

Let's say I have 3 elements, they start as

```
[False, False, False]
```

then I check them over the iterations like:

```
elements == [True, True, True]
```

The list of elements is fixed and should not grow (or shrink). You can think of these elements as switches, the input determines how many there are and they start all switched off. The only thing that can happen over time is that individual switches are turned on (True) by events happening in the iteration.

How does python do the checking and what is the cost?
What is the best way in terms of cost to check that?
Is there a way with bit operations or anything that checks all the elements at once?

Comment: Keep a **count** of the `True` values?

Comment: @StefanPochmann You could post this as an answer. In OP's case this is better than the answers suggesting `all`.

Comment: Python has `all` and `any` built-in functions, `all` returns `True` if all elements are evaluated to `True`, `any` returns `True` if at least one element is evaluated to `True`

Comment: @JohnColeman Well, if OP's actual list has only three elements, then `all` might be better. Keeping the count up to date takes time, too.

Comment: @StefanPochmann True -- but since they were concerned with efficiency I took 3 to be just an example. If the list is large enough for efficiency questions to even matter, then maintaining a count is better than repeatedly rechecking already settled cases.

Comment: @JohnColeman Maybe he wants it fast because he's checking a tiny list billions of times?

Comment: My initial thought was updating the list, potentially many times, and check it each times to stop the iteration as soon as every element is True. So counting is interesting, in terms of cost it is pretty clear: O(1) for every iteration to update the count and O(1) for each check of "trueness". How much does `all` cost? The example in the docs suggests O(n) for each check of "trueness" but I'm not sure how it is actually working.

Comment: The `all` function is for as far as I know, lazy. It's taking value from iterable, one by one and if False is given, the rest is not being checked and the result False is returned. However it dosen't change the O(n) scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bit operations to use a number as an array of flag bits. To get this to work we must encode your `True` as a cleared bit but `False` as a set bit. This way the number only becomes zero if all the bits are cleared.

This works nicely because the number of flags is fixed. By starting out with an array of set bits you only have to clear them until the number becomes zero.

This trades far faster condition checking for slight bit more complexity and cost in clearing the bits. Testing if a number is zero is far cheaper than applying `all` to any list of Booleans.

The comments on the question suggested keeping a count and the list. When one of the values becomes true the count either goes up to a final value of the length of the list or goes down from the length of the list to zero. That would work but it is redundant as the same fact is encoded twice once as the count and once as the number of Trues.

This combines the count and the list. It contains no redundancy.

Start out with 5 set bits:

```
>>> bin((1<<5)-1)
'0b11111'
```

Then clear them. This clears the 4th bit:

```
>>> bin(((1<<5)-1) & ~(1 << 3))
'0b10111'
```

This would allow your loop to have a condition like the following loop:

```
flags = (1<<5)-1
n = 0
while flags:
   flags &= ~(1<<n)
   print bin(flags)
   n += 1
```

This loop starts with 5 set bits and clears them one at a time.

```
>>> flags = (1<<5)-1
>>> n = 0
>>> while flags:
...    flags &= ~(1<<n)
...    print bin(flags)
...    n += 1
... 
0b11110
0b11100
0b11000
0b10000
0b0
```

Comment: *"you can't tell from a count which of the conditions had been tripped"* - But you can tell from the list. It doesn't have less debugging power.

Comment: It refers to the suggested count. Not to the list. Now if the suggestion was to keep a count and the list. That would be fine too but the count alone wouldn't.

Comment: That *is* the suggestion. Without the list, there are no `True` values to be counted. (And I doubt the count could be updated without the list.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all),

```
>>> l = [True, True, True]
>>> all(l)
True
```

Notice that if the iterable is empty, it will return `True` as well.

```
>>> all([])
True
```

Comment: `if l and all(l)` will do the work for empty list case

Comment: I deleted my comment as too pedantic. I know from teaching quantifiers in discrete math classes that a lot of students do struggle with the idea of vacuously true statements.

Comment: @JohnColeman, thx. Actually, I don't quite understand why `all([])` returns `True` as `int(True)` equals to `1`.

Comment: Either all birds can fly or there is a counterexample (a non-flying bird, such as a penguin). With an empty list, there are no counterexamples because there are no examples at all. No counterexamples implies that the universally quantified statement is true, though in a rather uninteresting way.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'd say it's the only **interesting** way :-). And it really bothers me that the Python doc says *"or if the iterable is empty"*.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own flag class, one which implements the idea of @StefanPochmann and keeps track of how many flags have been set.

Proof of concept:

```
class flags:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.__flags = [False]*n
        self.__ntrue = 0

    def flags(self):
        return self.__flags[:] #so read only

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__flags)

    def check(self,i):
        return self.__flags[i]

    def on(self,i):
        if not self.check(i):
            self.__ntrue +=1
            self.__flags[i] = True

    def off(self,i):
        if self.check(i):
            self.__ntrue -=1
            self.__flags[i] = False

    def toggle(self,i):
        if self.check(i):
            self.off(i)
        else:
            self.on(i)

    def ntrue(self):
        return self.__ntrue
```

Tested like:

```
import random

i = 0
f = flags(5)
while f.ntrue() != len(f):
    i +=1
    f.toggle(random.randint(0,4))

print(i,f.flags())
```

Typical output:

```
19 [True, True, True, True, True]
```

Comment: How about `while not f.all()`? Just like for example numpy arrays. Nice example usage, btw. (I had thought of almost the same, just with only "on" actions.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann `f.all()` does sound nice and would be easy enough to implement. Since it was meant as mostly proof-of-concept (e.g. it should have some error trapping added, not to mention things like `__str__` before it became fully usable), I'll leave it for OP to implement if they want to go this route.